# How to prevent fstream output from skipping to the next row in Excel when writing data using overloaded operators in C++

Tags: c++, io

So, I'm working with fstream to output data to an Excel sheet. I have a Base class and a derived class, and I'm trying to output some data using an overridden operator in the derived class. When I call the overridden operator in the Base class, everything works fine and I get the expected output. However, when I try to output additional data using my overridden operator in the derived class, it skips to the next record in the Excel sheet instead of staying on the same record.

In other words, I'm getting a new row in the Excel sheet for the additional data I'm trying to output, when I really want that data to be in the same row as the data outputted by the Base class's operator.

This is the code for the Base class operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& P)
{
    out << "First Name, Last Name, Age, Sex, Personal ID, Birthday/n";

    out << P.First_Name << "," << P.Last_Name <<
        "," << Page << "," << P.Sex
        << "," << P.personalID << ","
        << P.Birthday;

    return out;
}
```

and this is the code for the derived class operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Student& S)
{
    out << static_cast<Person&>(S) << "Number of Courses: " << S.numOfCourses << ",";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: look at what `operator<<` does for Person: It first writes a header then the data. You need to do the same for `Student`. You cannot reuse the `Person` implementation as you are doing it now

Comment: define with const Student param :  'ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Student& S)'

Comment: @jls28 The operator<< for the derived class Student needs to call the parent class Person's operator<< by using a static_cast. However, this cast requires that the reference to the object being casted is not a constant. Thus, the operator<< for Person cannot be defined as constant. This is the only way to make the operator<< for Student work correctly with the static_cast.

Answer (score 0):

The base class overload is poor design. It does too much at one: It writes a header (including a `\n`) and it writes the data. For the `Student` you need the `Person` and `Student` header and then the `Person` and `Student` data. With the current code this cannot be done. Refactor the `Person` overload to:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& P)
{
    P.writeHeader(out);
    out << "\n";
    P.writeData(out);
    return out;
}
```

Then you can reuse `Person::writeHeader` and `Person::writeData` when implementing the overload for `Student`.